# How to fix this issue "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated." in Android Studio?

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, android-virtual-device

I installed Android Studio for React Native and still stuck here for last two weeks. Let me show you a whole clip about it:

[This is the main issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh6q8.gif)

I have proper free space in my C drive and others as well but still getting the error and also have proper installations of softwares and drivers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2RNw.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFrkk.png

I have searched every possible solution on Stack Overflow and did all things which I found but couldn't solve this.

I just want to run the emulator and start my learning as a React Native Developer.

I would be happy to hear of a suitable replacement for Android Studio's emulator.